# Two number sum algorithm

Tags: algorithm, go

Time complexity of an algorithm below is O(log(n)), but I'm just curious what is time complexity of the for loop?

```golang
func TwoNumberSum(array[] int, target int)[] int {
    sort.Ints(array)
    left, right: = 0, len(array) - 1
    for left < right && left >= 0 && right < len(array) {
        if array[left] + array[right] == target {
            return [] int {
                array[left], array[right]
            }
        } else if array[left] + array[right] < target {
            left += 1
        } else {
            right -= 1
        }
    }
    return [] int {}
}
```

Comment: Curious why you have the conditions `left >= 0` and `right < len(array)`. `left` is initialized at 0 and is always incremented. `right` is initialized to `len(array)-1` and is always decreased. Those two conditions are completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

> Time complexity of an algorithm below is O(log(n))

The claim is incorrect. For `input = [1,2,3,4,5]` and `target = 9`, `left` will traverse the entire array. The complexity of the `for` loop, and for the entire algorithm, is `O(n)`.

Edit: I just noticed the extra `sort()` call. Sorting will make the algorithm's complexity `O(nlogn)`.